# Adding Return Button In Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikeyboard

I am making a customized iOS 8 keyboard. I created a button called Return and I'm stuck because I don't know how to make Return or Enter key work properly. I found many `textFielsShouldReturn` tutorials but I don't think it belongs to iOS keyboard extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I got it so easy in short time. This is what i did.

```
@IBAction func returnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText("\n")
}
```